# How does youtube use webrtc? Is it used frequently?

Tags: youtube, webrtc

I developed a video chat website for clients using webRTC.
This was my graduation project and I have worked hard and will use it as a portfolio for employment.
The company I want to go to is a video platform company like YouTube
However, I can not explain how I developed webRTC and how it will help the video platform company.
So I'm wondering how YouTube uses webRTC, and how video platform companies that do not use webRTC can use it
thank you

Answer (score 6):

> Youtube is not using WebRTC for video/live streaming.
>   If any website is using WebRTC, then we can easily inspect by opening below urls in browser:
>   [chrome://webrtc-internals/](http://chrome://webrtc-internals/)   for chrome.
>   [about:webrtc](http://about:webrtc) for firefox.

But recently YouTube started streaming video in VP9 video codec.
For live streaming youtube will depends on Hangouts on Air, which uses WebRTC.

**WebRTC:**

- Mostly WebRTC is using for Real time collaborations like Calls, Conferences & Presentations either in p2p or via SFU/MCU/B2B servers.
- We can use WebRTC to stream on youtube, by converting RTP to RTSP. See [Jitsi POC](https://jitsi.org/Projects/YouTubeLive).

Streaming Websites like YoutTube are okay with some delay in the streaming, but they have to scale for millions of viewers.

There are few common things in RealTime (WebRTC) & Non-RealTime/Near-RealTime applications:

- Audio & video synchronisation, i.e. lip-sync
- Optimising Encoder/Decoder for saving bandwidth and maintaining the quality
- Handling bad network conditions like packet drops or latency